# Capistrano deploy:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, capistrano3

I don´t have error when I do cap production deploy. the migration is successfull but is not in database.

```
deploy:migrating
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 == 20160506075320 DeviseCreateUsuarios: migrating ====================…
      01 -- create_table(:usuarios)
      01    -> 0.0038s
      01 -- add_index(:usuarios, :email, {:unique=>true})
      01    -> 0.0008s
      01 -- add_index(:usuarios, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
      01    -> 0.0008s
      01 == 20160506075320 DeviseCreateUsuarios: migrated (0.0054s) ===========…
      01
      01 == 20160511002957 AddColumnUidToUsuarios: migrating ==================…
      01 -- add_column(:usuarios, :provider, :string)
      01    -> 0.0006s
      01 -- add_column(:usuarios, :uid, :string)
      01    -> 0.0003s
      01 == 20160511002957 AddColumnUidToUsuarios: migrated (0.0010s) =========…
      01
```

my production.rb

```
set :stage, :production
server 'myserver.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
```

Comment: Do you have `:rails_env` set?

Comment: try this `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

Comment: 'RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate' was perfect. Thank you!